# How can I display super script number in text view iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I  want to display super script number in a simple text view can any one help me for that?

Comment: for example I want to diplay 14 or 3,4.

Comment: 0123456789: \u2070 \u00b9 \u00b2 \u00b3 \u2074 \u2075 \u2076 \u2077 \u2078 \u2079

Comment: Can I have uni codes for alphabets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UITextView` can't handle rich text so if you want to have superscripted numbers you have to build up a string using the unicode characters for superscripted numbers, e.g.

```
NSString *super0 = @"\u2070";
```

Gives you a superscripted zero. You can find the rest of the numerals [here on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts). You'll have to build up the string yourself from the individual digits but that will be a nice programming exercise.

Comment: When I wrote NSString *super0 = [NSString stringWithFormat:"@\U2070"];  I got error message like "error: incomplete universal character name \U2070"

Comment: OK, try my new one - I'm not at my mac at the moment so I am doing this from memory, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Under the Edit menu in Xcode there is a Special Characters option.

Comment: Plus also, if you search super script or subscript on here, it's been discussed before

Comment: Simon: can you please provide link where this topic has been discussed earlier?

Comment: That's a helluva thread resurrection.  If you'd have asked 15 months ago when this was posted, I probably could.  But even searching "iphone textview superscript" or something similar today, will yield plenty results.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int no=1; 
    NSString *str=@"xyz";
    *yourtextView*.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d",str,no];
```

Comment: XYZ™ here there is a TM after XYZ,in place TM of it I want to display any number.

Comment: what you have to do is seperate your string in two parts one containing string and other containing number. Then do*yourtextView*.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d",@"xyz",no];